# Disable "Start Dictation" for an app in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4

Is there a way to disable "Start Dictation" for a mac application? Basically, I am getting "Start Dictation..." menu in "Edit" Menu bar repeatedly. Any work around will be helpful.

Comment: Sounds like this [apple bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=764696) fixed in build 12A248 of Mountain Lion, and probably nothing to do with Qt other than the indirect use of NSMenu

Comment: I am on Mavericks and I have the same problem it was not fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the title property of your QMenu will prevent OS X from auto-adding silly things to your Edit menu.

So if I have a QMenuBar and I'm adding menus to it..

```
m_edit = this->addMenu(tr(" Edit"));
```

Notice I put a space in front of the text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename your menus to stop macOS messing with them. Adding a space in front of the menu item works, but it is a bit ugly. This is a classier way to do it using a zero width character:

```
menu->setTitle( menu->title().prepend( QString::fromUtf8( "\u200C" )  ) );
```

You can do it for all your top-level application menus like this in your QMainWindow derived class (tested on Qt 4.7):

```
#ifdef Q_OS_MACX
foreach ( QMenu* menu, menuBar()->findChildren<QMenu*>() )
{
    menu->setTitle( menu->title().prepend( QString::fromUtf8( "\u200C" )  ) );
}
#endif
```